# JQueryUI sortable with no placeholder displacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have multiple sortable columns (`<uls>`) next to one another with a number of `<li>` elements that you can drag between them. When you drag an option around, it displaces the other options below the cursor, even if I completely disable the placeholder. My preferred behavior is:

1. No displacement below the cursor.
2. When the item is dropped into the `<ul>`, it should be appended to the bottom of the list instead of wherever the cursor was hovering.

I've experimented with the forcePlaceholderSize property, as well as trying a placeholder with height 0, but neither seems to work (the former doesn't seem to have an effect regardless of whether or not it's true or false, and the latter always shows a placeholder with some sort of minimum height even if I override it with `!important` in the CSS).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322532/jquery-ui-sortable-sort-only-on-drop-event/30387678#30387678. you could possibly apply same logic, except at the end where you can set position to last item.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment from @JulienGrégoire pointing me in the right direction, I ended up adding the following to my sortable code to accomplish what I needed:

```
$( "ul.my_sortable" ).sortable({
    ...
    start: function (event, ui) {
        // get placeholder position when selecting item
        place_prev = ui.placeholder.prev();
        start_col = $(this);
        target_col = $(this)
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
        // keep track of where the placeholder moves...
        place_pos = ui.placeholder.index();
        // and reset it back to its starting position so it doesn't appear to move
        place_prev.after(ui.placeholder);
    },
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        // move the choice to the correct column when you let go
        if (!target_col.is(start_col)) {
            target_col.append(ui.item);
        }
    }
});
```

This still seems a bit inefficient though, constantly babysitting the placeholder. If anyone else can come up with a better way, I'd love to hear it!