# Jquery sortable - Prevent items from shifting after moving

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a way of preventing the list items inside the sortable being shifted once some are moved?

[image]

For example, if I moved '2' on to a droppable area, '3' would fill in the empty space. *I do not want to absolutely position the list items...*

Comment: ..? On the demo, items shift when you drag one. I don't want the items to shift/fill the empty space. I want them to stay where they are.

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322532/jquery-ui-sortable-sort-only-on-drop-event/30387678#30387678

Comment: Nope :(.. See the new image..

Comment: I would bind to the `drop` event in draggable. If you use a clone or a helper object when you drag '2' out, when you drop, you can replace the original with '3', without a disruption to the layout.